# Parse - Querying for objects NOT in query

Tags: javascript, objective-c, parse-platform

My user class has a relation "Following" for all users that they follow. That's being populated just fine. Each user also has a "FacebookID" column that is of type String. I want to query for all users that are NOT in the "Following" relationship.

For instance, let's say I have users A, B, and C where A is following B. My query, for user A, should return C because that is the only user that A is NOT following.

Here is the code I'm using currently (It's in Objective-C, but feel free to respond in any language. I'm familiar with Parse in JS, Java, Swift, and Obj-C):

```
PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
PFRelation *follows = user[@"Follows"];

PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
//Make sure it's not in the followers
[query whereKey:@"FacebookID" doesNotMatchKey:@"FacebookID" follows.query];
//Make sure it's not the current user
[query whereKey:@"FacebookID" notEqualTo:user[@"FacebookID"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * _Nullable objects, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    NSLog(@"Found %lu users that the current user doesn't follow.", objects.count);
}];
```

This works, but as soon as the user's following count gets over 1000, it won't because the relation will only return the first 1000.

I only want to find around 10 people in the entire userbase at a time that they don't follow, not necessarily all of them. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: So you're trying to accomplish a "suggested people to follow" kind of capability right? If that's the case, then you probably want to suggest people that your followers are following but you are not currently

Comment: Kind of. I've simplified the problem a bit for this post as this is the core problem in a bigger challenge. That query wouldn't work for what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spoke to a Parse engineer and it seems that the type of query I want to do IS in fact limited by the 1000 object response limit so I would avoid this on the Parse platform going forward. He mentioned that it's something on their radar so hopefully it won't be a problem going forward!

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies in the user of `whereKey:doesNotMatchKey:inQuery:`, but I'm uncertain about your data model.  Is `Follows` a relation with a target class of PFUser?  In that case, the query you want can then be stated concisely as...

```
PFRelation *follows = user[@"Follows"];
PFQuery *innerQuery = [follows query];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
query.limit = // your choice, up to 1000
[query whereKey:@"objectId" doesNotMatchKey:@"objectId" inQuery:innerQuery];
```

Notice that this doesn't refer to the "FacebookID" string column on user to which the OP refers.  It needn't, if the follows relation to user is setup properly.

Comment: While that's basically the same query, just using a different column (it doesn't matter as I need my FacebookID column for other reasons anyway), it still doesn't solve the problem. [follows query] will only yield 1000 results so if the person is following more than 1000 people, it will result in the outer query returning users who the user DOES follow, but were NOT in the first 1000 of the inner query.

Comment: Do you know this to be the case, or are you speculating?  It's a reasonable speculation, I admit, but so is the reverse, that more objects are processed internally in order to fulfill the logical promise, and its just the quantity returned to the client that is limited to 1k.  If it operates as you suppose, then (a) isn't it broken, failing to fulfill an implied promise of the spec, (b) how can you expect any incantation to return what you're looking for?

Comment: Would be thrilled if you tried the above and either: (a) it works... success, or (b) you demonstrate that it doesn't work; such a demonstration -- to me -- would be a clear bug, or (c) if I'm wrong about (b), somebody set me straight about it.

Comment: Just spoke to a Parse engineer. The queries work as I described. It seems this type of query isn't necessarily possible with today's system.

Comment: Sounds like an answer.